# how to Make sure the dataflow logs are written to Storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

how to Make sure the dataflow logs are written to Storage bucket in GCP

can please help anyone regarding it

Answer (score 0):

The `Dataflow` logs are visibles in the job UI page showing the Dataflow DAG.

The logs are also written in `Cloud Logging`.

The `Dataflow` logs are not directly written in a file in `Cloud Storage`.

If you want to write logs to `Cloud Storage` file, you have to do that in a sink explicitly.

For example, you can write error logs in a file in `Cloud Storage` with a dead letter queue.

A dead letter queue is a way of treating messages in another queue in the job with side outputs.